# In the make file difference between normal assignment and assignment with export

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

What is the difference between assigning with export and without export in Makefile.
Example:

```
export PROTOCOMPILER_RETIMING=1
FILELIST = ../src/haps_pcie_sa_test.lst
```

Can anyone explain in detail

Answer (score 1):

`export` will export the variable to *sub-makes*, which are recursive invocations of make. Example:

**Makefile**

```
VARIABLE = Hello
all:
    $(MAKE) -C foo  # runs make in subdirectory foo
```

**foo/Makefile**

```
all:
    echo $(VARIABLE)
```

This will print nothing, because `VARIABLE` is not being exported to the sub-make run for the subdirectory `foo`. If we add `export VARIABLE` to the top-level `Makefile`, however, we do get `Hello` printed to the console.

More information: [Variables/Recursion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html#Variables_002fRecursion) in the GNU make manual.